# How to update component on state change in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, django-rest-framework

I am trying to update component on state change in redux. I have a list of images, when user deletes the image the component should update after deleting the targeted image.

I have tried using componentWillReceiveProps and componentDidUpdate life cycle method, but none is working here. Can someone please suggest me what I am doing wrong here?

what I have done so far

**action**

```
import { DELETE_GALLERY_SUCCESS, DELETE_GALLERY_FAIL} from "./types";

export const deleteGalleryImage = (id) => (dispatch, getState) => {
    axios    
        .delete(`${baseURL}/api/aws/gallery/${id}/delete/`, tokenConfig(getState))

        .then(res => {
            dispatch({
                type: DELETE_GALLERY_SUCCESS,
                payload: res.data
            });


        })
        .catch(err => {
            dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status));
            dispatch({
                type: DELETE_GALLERY_FAIL
            });
        });
};
```

**types.js**

```
export const DELETE_GALLERY_SUCCESS = "DELETE_GALLERY_SUCCESS"
export const DELETE_GALLERY_FAIL = "DELETE_GALLERY_FAIL"
```

**Reducer**

```
import {DELETE_GALLERY_SUCCESS, DELETE_GALLERY_FAIL} from "../actions/types";

const initialState = {
    paginations: true,
    isLoading: false,
    gallery: [],

};


export default function (state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case DELETE_GALLERY_SUCCESS:
           return {
                ...state,
                isLoading: false,
                gallery: state.gallery.filter(gallery => gallery.id !== action.payload)
            };

        case DELETE_GALLERY_FAIL:
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoading: false
            };

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Here is my **component**

```
import { getAllGalleryImages, deleteGalleryImage } from '../settings/../../actions/gallery';


class DeleteGalleryImage extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getAllGalleryImages();
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (this.props.images !== nextProps.images) {

            // This is not working.
            // what life cycle method should I use for this scenario?

            //this.props.getAllGalleryImages()

        }
    }
    handleDelete = (id) => {
        this.props.deleteGalleryImage(id)
    }    
    render() {
        return (

            <Row>
                <Col xs={24} sm={22} offset={1}>
                    <h1 className='sub-page-heading'><span className='common_dlt'>Delete</span> Gallery Image</h1>
                    <div className='masonry'>

                        {this.props.images && this.props.images.results && this.props.images.results.map(result =>


                            <div className='masonry-item' key={result.id}>
                                <img src={result.gallery_img_url} className='dlt_blg_img' alt='img' id={result.id} />
                                <span className='gallery_delete_zone' onClick={() => this.handleDelete(result.id)}><Icon type="delete" /></span>
                            </div>

                        )}

                    </div>
                </Col>
            </Row>
        )
    }
}   
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    images: state.gallery

});
export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    { getAllGalleryImages, deleteGalleryImage }
)(DeleteGalleryImage);
```

**Store**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import rootReducer from "./reducers";

const initialState = {};

const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
);

export default store;
```

rootReducer

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import gallery from './gallery';

    export default combineReducers({
      gallery,

    });
```

Comment: `gallery: state.gallery.filter(gallery => gallery.id !== action.payload)`, is action.payload an id here ?

Comment: And you do not update the state in your reducer after deleting, apart from the `isLoading` property

Comment: Please change any state in your reducer for updating component otheriwse you can also use this.forceupdate() in your component manually.

Comment: I think this line  payload: res.data   must be  payload: id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case no need to use componentWillReceiveProps, If you can change the store succcesfully the component will be rendered automatically since it is connected to the store.

Another thing I noticed is  in your deleteGalleryImage  action, I think you need to send id input parameter as payload, because we cannot assume if res.data will be id.

```
dispatch({
    type: DELETE_GALLERY_SUCCESS,
    payload: id
})
```

**Edit**: based on the info I got from comments, I understood your initial state

```
const initialState = {
        count: 2,
        gallery: {},
        isLoading: true,
        next: null,
        paginations: true,
        previous: null,
        results: [{}, {}]

};
```

So your DELETE_GALLERY_SUCCCESS case must be like this if you want to remove a image in results array.

```
   case DELETE_GALLERY_SUCCESS:
           return {
                ...state,
                  isLoading: false,
                  results: state.results.filter(image => image.id !== action.payload)
                }
            };
```

Comment: I tried the same, but its not updating the component

Comment: @ConAra can you add the code where you create your store?

Comment: @ConAra another thing, why do you map this.props.images.results? 
 What is the shape of your gallery array in store?

Comment: Ok there seems no problem, what about my other question?

Comment: {"count":3,"next":null,"previous":null,"results":[{"id":47,"gallery_img_url":"https://mysite-2.s3.amazonaws.com/gallery/1.jpg"},{"id":46,"gallery_img_url":"https://mysite-2.s3.amazonaws.com/gallery/3.jpg"},{"id":45,"gallery_img_url":"https://mysite-2.s3.amazonaws.com/gallery/CaptureB.PNG"}]}

Comment: Is this only one item in gallery array? You have multiple galleries and in every gallery there are results array?

Comment: yes, there is only one item in gallery array (The main object, I guess) and inside this there will be one results array containing list of images available

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200782/discussion-between-suleymansah-and-conara).

Comment: @ConAra  I edited my answer can you update your reducer as in the answer and try?